# OrientDB PHP/Gremlin Bridge

Tags: php, groovy, orientdb, gremlin

I am using OrientDb and want to run Gremlin commands through PHP. Does anybody know if there are any bridges or products that can connect the 2 languages?

Whilst I am aware of OrientDB-PHP and the OrientDB-REST packages, neither allow execution of Gremlin commands.

Alternatively, where would be the best place to start learning about how to write and implement such a piece of script?

Answer (score 0):

Using the REST protocol send a HTTP POST to this URL:

http://localhost:2480/command/demo/gremlin

With this content: g.V

For more information look at http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/OrientDB_REST#POST_-_Command

Answer (score 0):

There is a project working on abstracting out the ODB (and other graph databases) SQL (and Gremlin too).

It is called Spider.

https://github.com/spider/spider

It is still in alpha and there is a good bit of work to do, but if anything, it should help you later with running queries over a number of graph databases (not just ODB). It should also allow direct querying of Gremlin too.

Please follow the repo and even give some feedback.

Scott